# Still can't login without password after ssh-copy-id command success

Tags: linux, ssh

I've searched and tried many solutions in the internet on why I can't still do passwordless remote server access but I can't seem to make it work.

I have followed this step in creating a ssh key and copy to remote server:

1. First, I have cleanup my `authorized_key` & `known_hosts` files so there are no more registered key in there both my local server and remote server.
2. I then begin to create ssh key and type this below:

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/local_key`

This is the result after I hit enter:

`Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/local_key.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/local_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:yZ3CgQ2CtyMJHyvkGFyZNQ5U7XX1RzD8SOm9bxCbODg user@myserver
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|. o=*+o     .ooo.|
|oooo+..= . .  =o |
|++ = oo + .  o =.|
|o.= o  + + .  + +|
| . . .  S o. . +.|
|         .E o +. |
|           . . ..|
|                o|
|               . |
+----[SHA256]-----+`

4. I then copied public key to the remote server:

   `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/local_key.pub user@myremoteserver`
5. Then I was prompt by this and typed my password:

```
     /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/user/.ssh/local_key.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@myremoteserver's password:

    Number of key(s) added: 1

    Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user@myremoteserver'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

I tried doing `ssh 'user@myremoteserver'` or `scp` to copy files, but still it requires password.

**EDIT**: Here's the output after running command `ssh -v user@myremoteserver`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myremoteserver [10.1.250.174] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 7c:ef:fc:81:8a:02:35:8f:c2:a6:5a:fb:af:ef:9e:95
debug1: Host 'myremoteserver' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:54339)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:54339)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@myremoteserver's password:
```

**UPDATE:**

I have followed your suggestions to add permissions 700 on `.ssh` and 600 on `authorized_keys`. I run this script `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/local_key.pub user@myremoteserver` and then I got this:

```
The authenticity of host 'myremoteserver (10.1.250.174)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 7c:ef:fc:81:8a:02:35:8f:c2:a6:5a:fb:af:ef:9e:95.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@myremoteserver's password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user@myremoteserver'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

After all of that, I'm still ask for password. :(

Comment: Do `ssh -v 'user@myremoteserver'` (note `-v`) to see what happens, and why the key doesn't work (there are multiple ways this can go wrong).

Comment: @dirkt I have updated my question to show the output of `ssh -v`.

Comment: According to your update, your client does try to authenticate using `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`. The next suspect would be sshd configuration on the remote server. Make sure your `$HOME/.ssh` is 700 chmoded, belongs to your user, that the `authorized_keys file` is 600 chmoded and also belongs to that user. If both are OK, then make sure your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` doesn't set a custom `authorizedKeysFile` (and if it does, make sure your key is in that file). Eventually, you could keep an eye on system logs (`journalctl -f`) while trying to connect, there may be something explaining your issue

Answer (score 4):

The key `ssh` is using by default is `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/local_key.pub user@myremoteserver` should work in your case.

You can adjust `.ssh/config` so ssh will use a specific key for a specific server.

See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545520/364705) to [a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545510/how-to-create-pem-file-full-process) for a snippet to do all the necessary steps at once.

Comment: I tried running `less .ssh/config` but there's no such file or directory. It doesn't exist in my server.

Comment: It doesn't exist unless you create it yourself.  See point 3 of my referenced answer.

Comment: I gaveup. I use `ssh-keygen` directly and `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@myremoteserver` just to make it work. I don't know why it wouldn't accept a custom file name directly. If I add that config file would that solve my problem? Sorry I'm not that expert in this ssh thing.

Comment: The ssh  config file just tells ssh which key to use where, so you don't need to specify it on the command line by `ssh -i somekey`.  You can also define shorthands for long hostnames.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if SELinux is enabled on target server .

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.