# How to create .pem file - full process

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I want to create a .pem file to connect to the server.

I know that I can use ssh-keygen, But I want to use it for a specific user, And I need a script that will do for me all process.
My need is to run the script one time on server X and so each time that I want to connect to X server I can use this the .pem file, in my computer to connect to the X server.

Comment: So you want to run a script on a server in order to produce an ssh-key for a user?  Which the user would already *need to have* in order to run the script?

What is the problem you are trying to solve???

Comment: I edited it. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Please be aware that certificates and keys are different techniques. You are trying to setup key authentication but refer to a format to store certificates.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do this the other way around.

There is no need to have the private key lying around on the remote computer.

1. Generate the key-pair on your local machine:
   `ssh-keygen -f .ssh/somekey -t rsa -b 4096`
2. Then copy it to the remote machine
   `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/somekey user@hostname`
3. And then adjust your local `.ssh/config`:

```bash
$ cat << BLURB >> .ssh/config 
Host shorthand
    HostName server.com
    User serveruser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/somekey
BLURB
```

You can easily wrap these three steps in a script `genandcopykey.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash - 
#         USAGE: ./genandcopykey.sh user@example.com charlie@example.org ...
#
#   DESCRIPTION: creates an ssh-keypair, copies pubkey to remotehost
#                and updates .ssh/config to use it

set -o nounset   # exit on unset variables.
set -o errexit   # exit on any error.
unalias -a       # avoid rm being aliased to rm -rf and similar issues
LANG=C           # avoid locale issues

for item in $@; do
    remoteuser="${item%@*}" # everything in front of the first "@"
    remotehost="${item#*@}" # everything after

    ssh-keygen  -f "${HOME}/.ssh/${item}" -t rsa -b 4096
    ssh-copy-id -i "${HOME}/.ssh/${item}.pub" "$item"

printf '%s\n' "
Host $remotehost
    HostName $item
    User $remoteuser
    IdentityFile ${HOME}/.ssh/${item}" >> $HOME/.ssh/config
done
```

You may still want to add options and a usage-function to the script.  This is only a short example and lacks in errorhandling for nonexistent hosts or existing files in `.ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, and I didn't find an answer about how to do it, so I post it.

```
#! /bin/bash
    #Based on https://linuxaws.wordpress.com/2017/07/17/how-to-generate-pem-file-to-ssh-the-server-without-password-in-linux/
    user=$(echo "$USER")
    ssh-keygen << EOF
    $user
    EOF
    mv $user $user.pem
    sudo chmod    700   ~/.ssh
    touch  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    sudo chmod   600  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    cat $user.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo "Copy the $user.pem to your computer."
```

After you run this script on a server or computer you can connect to it from another server/computer, with the command

```
ssh -i <pem_filename>.pem user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script below for ec2 instances to create a Key based sudo user. Kindly try this.

Note: below script works for all linux OS like redhat, ubuntu, suse, kali, centos, fedora, amazon linux 1/2, debain......etc

```
#!/bin/bash
#author: bablish jaiswal
#purpos: a sudo pem based user creation
clear
#echo "Hi, I am a function to create a sudo user with pem file. Kindly share following information"
echo -e "\n\n\n"
printf "\e[6;33mHi, I am a function to create sudo user with pem file. Kindly share following information\e[0m";echo
read -p "user name:- " name #input your name
read -p "complete path for $name home directory:- " home #user home directory
sudo useradd  -m -d $home $name -s /bin/bash #create user by given input
sudo -u $name cat /dev/zero | sudo -u $name ssh-keygen  -q -N "" #generating pem 
sudo -u $name  mv $home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $home/.ssh/authorized_keys #permission
sudo chmod 700 $home/.ssh #permission again
sudo chmod 600 $home/.ssh/authorized_keys #permission again and again
echo " "
#echo "-------Copy below pem file text---------"
printf "\e[6;33m-----------------------------Copy below text-------------------------\e[0m";echo
sudo cat $home/.ssh/id_rsa
echo " "
#echo "-------Copy above text---------"
#svalue=$(cat /etc/sudoers |grep -i root |grep -i all|tail -n1 |awk '{$1=""}1') 
svalue=$(cat /etc/sudoers |grep -i root |grep -i all|tail -n1 |awk '{print $2}') #sudo creation
echo "${name} ${svalue} NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && echo “Remark:- User $name is a sudo user” #sudo confirmation message
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make RSA key pair on your server with `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

A key length of 4096 bits is recommended for establishing a secure connection between two machines.

insert your passphrase. Just make it blank if you don't use it.

Add your public key to `authorized_keys`

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

or you can add it manually using your text editor in your server.

Copy your private key in your server

```
cp .ssh/id_rsa /home/your_user/your_key.pem
```

Now in your client PC, download a key from server

```
scp your_user@yourhostserver.com:/home/your_user/your_key.pem /home/your_user/Downloads/
```

Now test your ssh connection

```
ssh your_user@yourhostserver.com -i '/home/your_user/Downloads/your_key.pem'
```